# Set-cookie is intermittently not being obeyed

Tags: asp.net, browser, cookies

I have an asp.net mvc application which is authenticating a username/password and if correct setting a cookie in the browser and doing a 302 to another page.

For some reason though the browser will ignore the set-cookie and thus never stores the cookie. The weird thing is:

1. The exact same code on my local environment works perfectly even though the same code run in my test environment in a different tab fails
2. It works perfectly in some browsers but not others
3. It will sometimes work in a browser that previously failed to work

   I have opened up fiddler and have been comparing the requests/responses and everything looks identical. Can anyone give any suggestions of whats going on?

*Not working*

Login response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://foo.test/bar
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 2.0
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=7C02633DAD998CB9CD25CC413FF34506DBF9095B78FC69FD03F83C4F7A091BF45469D389510F5ADD286AB6131EEC14609199C9CAD6B82E2BAFB61DE382BC34A65B72FEE5A9DD53820250E339FB6B863974C91F25CD2BE53646296C6E72F6C18F53C4BE7F9977CE9DB58647D9190093A167DCCBC698D5D4803739D0ECDA4621E744FF886EF7E0E1D3B0ED4A12FB08E34D521F20AA5C9549C66BD3171C68313E70E0ACCB851FA7A7D1509EF30345998A80DF0577F38A8C85E141C4F17803205CDDE05DD2C9; expires=Wed, 22-Dec-2010 16:45:06 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 01 Jan 2012 15:36:01 GMT
Content-Length: 220

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://foo.test/bar">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Next request (note no new cookie):

```
GET https://foo.test/bar HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.test
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100611 Firefox/3.6.4
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,fr;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://foo.test/login
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=oskgcf45t5oqvo453kmftw45;
```

*Working*

Login response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://foo.local/bar
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 2.0
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=CE23F217A77AC4D7DE76D16EDC27B21257973DECEF8F85D2FD3E345D051C81BE42F35978884BF7E508BF298824BADE1461C56966F5C6A2BF96F2E99F038068CBC068755494A3CD36BB2283040378982B7F96C76E1E2DCF1F6F481AB9C1399D7CFADF30B3049BDE7E94215DF58D091364974C69399AF92B0E03A10C3BF25907DC187060E681D4867E24DBB39F2D26659FDCDCD661DF8DFD88ABD7E4D931207614611013CA68065F7805D055E1FFF72B91C07C5576D4581FB9E4A04029E51E0A78ADD6B894; expires=Wed, 22-Dec-2010 16:49:34 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 22 Dec 2010 16:19:34 GMT
Content-Length: 221

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://foo.local/bar">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Next request (note the new cookie):

```
GET https://local.toptable.com/ism/confirm?c=2&o=True&v=1313&t=12-00&d=21-12-2010&l=True HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.local
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100611 Firefox/3.6.4
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,fr;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://foo.local/login
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=5aefag4544y4pvqht1k3k455; .ASPXAUTH=CE23F217A77AC4D7DE76D16EDC27B21257973DECEF8F85D2FD3E345D051C81BE42F35978884BF7E508BF298824BADE1461C56966F5C6A2BF96F2E99F038068CBC068755494A3CD36BB2283040378982B7F96C76E1E2DCF1F6F481AB9C1399D7CFADF30B3049BDE7E94215DF58D091364974C69399AF92B0E03A10C3BF25907DC187060E681D4867E24DBB39F2D26659FDCDCD661DF8DFD88ABD7E4D931207614611013CA68065F7805D055E1FFF72B91C07C5576D4581FB9E4A04029E51E0A78ADD6B894
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the "Not Working" login response, the server's `Date:` header has the value `Sun, 01 Jan 2012 15:36:01 GMT` (the future!), and your cookie expiration is set for `Wed, 22-Dec-2010 16:45:06 GMT` which will cause the browser to immediately expire the cookie, thus not storing it.

Comment: ah thanks, I'm going to spend some time investigating this (http://serverfault.com/questions/217343/date-header-returned-by-iis7-is-wrong)